# Bitbucket: is there some user password other than Atlassian password?

Tags: passwords, bitbucket

I used bitbucket a lot in the past (mostly because of the private repos). Have not used it for a while and now I always get "fatal: Authentication failed" error when trying to clone a repo. I feel it may be related to this whole Atlassian thing because now I cannot find how to configure bitbucket user password, only Atlassian password. That's why I am asking: is there some other bitbucket user password and is there any way to change it?

All I see after clicking in the upper right corner when logged in bitbucket is "Manage Atlassian account, View profile, Bitbucket settings, Integrations, Log ot". Password changing is only located in "Manage Atlassian account".

This what I've done so far (without success):

- changed password (several times, now it consists of the small letters only)
- played with variations of URL (with/out username, adding password to url)
- deleted bitbucket account and created a new one (however, connected to the same Atlassian account as before)
- tested via different networks at home/work.

Nothing worked so far. The same result on different computers (Windows and Linux). In the same time I can clone Github repos and work with them as usual. I need HTTPS only.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to configure your SSH keys properly. Login to Bitbucket through the web browser. Click on your icon in the top right corner and click on Bitbucket Settings from the pop-up menu. On the next screen will be a Settings menu on the left hand side. Click on SSH keys. If you already have SSH keys setup on your computer you can add your current keys. If you don't you'll need to create some keys, usually done with the ssh-keygen command line tool. This should generate two files, id_rsa and id_rsa.pub. Open the id_rsa.pub file and copy the contents to your clip board. Back in your web browser click the Add Key button. Give it a label and paste the contents of your clipboard into the Key text box.

You'll need to make sure git is set to use this key when you connect either through an SSH config file.

Comment: I can use only HTTPS. As I have said, github works via HTTPS and only bitbucket does not. Also checked via different networks at home/work.

Comment: As far as I've understood there is Atlassian account that is now connected to bitbucket. A question is the following: does Atlassian user substitute bitbucket user (because I cannot find how to change bitbucket password) and what can solve a possible case that I am facing.

Comment: Are you setting the correct username in the URL? https://username@bitbucket.org/username/reponame.git ? Are you being prompted for a password?

Comment: Yep, everything seems correct, I am being propted for password, and the working password is not being accepted - in both work and home networks and on both work and home computers, after recreating user account also. 
The only thing that I have not tried yet is creating bitbucket (and also Atlassian) account with another e-mail, I guess I should try it. New bitbucket account that I have created is still connected to same Atlassian user.

Comment: Also tried changing the password and making it very simple - only small letters.

Comment: It worked with creating a brand new user with another email.

Answer (score 1):

Everything works after creating a brand new user for both Bitbucket and Atlassian with another email.